# Identifying active iup dialog

Tags: lua, iup

I'm writing a lua program that needs to call an external popup (let's call it Poppy) provided as an external library/API by another active programme (environment is Windows).

Poppy has a bad habit; when invoked, it pops up, does its work and then vanishes -- leaving the current Lua dialog hidden behind Poppy's parent program.

After calling Poppy, `dlg.BRINGFRONT="YES"` will bring the iup dialog `dlg` to the front.

Is there a technique to identify what `dlg` should be -- i.e. what was the topmost iup dialog before the external API was invoked?

I've read the iup documentation and can't see a way to do this. However, as I need to call Poppy in a large number of instances, I'd like to simplify the process of bringing the current dialog to the front.

I'm invoking Poppy thus:

```
local res = Poppy('INDI')
dlg.BRINGFRONT="YES"
return res
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've succeeded in doing this using the [Winapi library](http://stevedonovan.github.io/winapi/api.html) and the following code:

```
winapi = require ("winapi")
currentwin = winapi.get_foreground_window()
--invoke Poppy here and wait for control to return
currentwin:set_foreground()
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the code that invokes Poppy in Windows, you can call:

```
HWND dlg_handle = GetActiveWindow();
```

Then when Poppy returns, call:

```
SetForegroundWindow(dlg_handle);
```

Comment: The only coding vehicle I have is Lua with a restricted set of libraries so I can't immediately see how I'd do this.